# Is this Second for time or just an ordinal number?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "Clement also introduced the pendulum suspension spring in 1671. The
>   concentric minute hand was added to the clock by Daniel Quare, a
>   London clock-maker, and the **Second** Hand was introduced."
>   ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_timekeeping_devices#Era_of_precision_timekeeping))

It's not understood to me if this word Second refers to time (second) or to the ordinal number. However, I don't understand the reason for the capital letter in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second hand (in its temporal sense) was the third hand (in the ordinal sense).

In the given context, the concentric minute hand was added to another hand that already existed.  It seems natural enough to count the hour hand as the first.

Comment: Thanks. So in the given context it means to the temporal sense, right? What's the capital letter for?

Comment: To my native reader's eye, the capitalization is odd.  Perhaps the author or editor wants to treat "second hand" as a proper name as a way to help resolve the ambiguity.